# Yii2 custom login-logout

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to use 'login/register' & 'logout' links as shown in following images - [image: login/register snap]. Here I'm using custom template theme, So, I don't want to use default Navigation Bar. But I want to use Yii2's default login & logout functions. For that, I'm using following code in my 'layouts/main.php' -

```
<?php
            if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
                echo '<h2><a href="index.php?r=site/login">Login </a><a href="index.php?r=site/signup">Register</a></h2>';
            } else {
                echo '<h2><a href="index.php?r=site/index">Logout</a></h2>';
            }
        ?>
```

Normally, my scenario is - firstly, it will display 'login/register' links if the user is not logged in. After a successful login, it will display 'logout' link instead of 'login/register'. Then, after clicking on 'logout' link, it should disply 'login/register' by logging out.

BUT the issue with this code is, after logging in, it displays a fix 'logout' link as follows - [image: snap with 'logout'], which is not changing back to 'login/register' even we clicked on 'logout'. The page refreshes & again shows 'logout'. It remains fixed to 'logout', untill we clear browser's coockies,cache.

So, please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace href from `site/index` to `site/logout`

```
else {
    echo '<h2><a data-method="post" href="index.php?r=site/logout">Logout</a></h2>';
}
```

Also instead of writing href directly, use [`Url::to()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to%28%29-detail) method, it is more flexible and if you decide to use pretty urls it will handle this automatically for you, and your links will become from *index.php?r=site/logout* to *site/logout* without changing any code.

```
else {
    echo '<h2><a data-method="post" href="' . Url::to(['site/logout']) . '">Logout</a></h2>';
}
```

Comment: Can I use it like this - 'Url::to(['index.php?r=site/logout'])'  ?

Comment: After using this, it now shows - ' Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: POST. '

Comment: The usage is `Url::to(['controller/action'])`. if you not use pretty urls it will return to you `index.php?r=site/login`

Comment: add `data-method="post"` to your link

Comment: yeah, but where should I add this?

Comment: Since I'm not using the default template theme, I want to show 'login/register' or 'logout' as I shown in images above. Therefore I'm not using their default Nav-Bar on which we can add menuItems with 'data-method'.

Comment: do you have _yii.js_ on your page ?

Comment: Thanks bro ! It now works with - echo '<h2><a data-method="post" href="'. Url::to(['site/logout']) .'">Logout</a></h2>';